# How do I write a Solr FunctionQuery to boost documents with future dates?

Tags: search, solr, relevance

Am trying to boost records with a particular date in the future closest to now towards the top of the results, and make those with dates in the past less relevant. I've seen a number of posts about how to boost results which are just closer to now, but that's not really what I need.

Comment: So, the closer the dates are to `NOW`, but still in the future, they are great. But as soon as `NOW` is passed, they shall be at the end of the list?

Comment: Kind of, but more like first comes dates in the future prioritized closer to `NOW`, then dates in the past prioritized closer to `NOW`.

Comment: So, if say `NOW=2012-12-30` and there are the dates `A=2012-12-31`, `B=2012-12-29` and `C=2013-01-30`, then the score of A shall be better than the of B. But what about the score of C, better than the one of B? Could you give a more detailed example in your question?

Comment: In this case, the preferred order would be `A, C, B`

Comment: Further, let's add `D=2012-11-30` and `E=2012-12-01`. The preferred order would be `A,C,B,E,D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. Know if the date is in the future or the past
2. Use different boost functions for each case

Assuming the field name is **due_date**, we'll start building your query.

First, you want to get the time difference.

```
&timediff=ms(due_date,NOW)
```

*You can use NOW/HOUR, NOW/DAY for better performance*

Second, we need to know if duration is positive or negative: adding a number to its absolute value will return 1/true on positive and 0/false on negative.

```
&future=sum($timediff,abs($timediff)
```

Now depending whether the number is positive or negative you want to apply different boost functions. You can use any function you want here.

```
&futureboost=recip($timediff,1,36000000,36000000)
&pastboost=recip($timediff,1,3600000,3600000)
$finalboost=if($future,$futureboost,$pastboost)
&boost=$finalboost
```

Notice that futureboost parameters are 10x more than pastboost which will give higher boost to future documents than past ones. The recip function is documented on the [Solr Function Query page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#recip) and you can tune the parameters of both futureboost and pastboost functions to your case.

To return the function value, you can use:

```
&fl=_DATE_BOOST_:$finalboost
```

Full Query will be a combination of all the above:

```
&timediff=ms(due_date,NOW/HOUR)
&future=sum($timediff,abs($timediff)
&futureboost=recip($timediff,1,36000000,36000000)
&pastboost=recip($timediff,1,3600000,3600000)
$finalboost=if($future,$futureboost,$pastboost)
&boost=$finalboost
&fl=_DATE_BOOST_:$finalboost
```

Comment: This effectively covers it. I had to modify a bit to add a second diff for past dates, `&pastdiff=ms(NOW/HOUR,due_date)&pastboost=recip($pastdiff,1,360000,3600000)` because using the other one would be negative. Could also use `abs` there I suppose. Sadly using `if` requires Solr 4 which isn't yet an option for us in production, but I don't see any other way to do this as effectively you must do an `if` check to query correctly

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by applying the below boost query :

```
bq=movie_release_date:[NOW/DAY-1MONTH TO NOW/DAY+2MONTHS]^10
```

Not that accurate as the previous answer, but in case you lack Solr 4, it results pretty much the same.